# Only check date condition when DateTime?(nullable?) using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I need check if any record exists on current date. But `AddOn` is nullable date. If I check below condition is throwing error because I am trying get date from null.

```
var cusRelationships = SvcClient.Client.Context.CusRelationships.Where(c =>
             c.CustomerId == identity.rCustomerId &&
             c.AddedOn.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).Select(c => c).ToList();
```

How compare date for current date?

Comment: No property 'Date' exists in type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Answer (score 2):

Just check for null before the using the Value.

```
var cusRelationships = SvcClient.Client.Context.CusRelationships.Where(c =>
                 c.CustomerId == identity.rCustomerId &&
                 c.AddedOn.HasValue &&
                 c.AddedOn.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).Select(c => c).ToList();
```

Comment: No property 'Date' exists in type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Comment: I don't think that works. Because I have a record that date. it says No property 'Date' exists in type 'System.Nullable`

Comment: Is there any otherway to check?

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure AddedOn is a nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

```
var cusRelationships = SvcClient.Client.Context.CusRelationships
    .Where(c =>
               c.CustomerId == identity.rCustomerId &&
               c.AddedOn.HasValue &&
               c.AddedOn.Value.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
    .Select(c => c)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `"The expression ((([10007].CustomerId == \"3002347\") And [10007].AddedOn.HasValue) And ([10007].AddedOn.Value.ToShortDateString() == \"1/27/2016\")) is not supported."}. ` I am passing this in Dataservice. looks it will not support for this